# Valid Hijri Date shown as invalid in moment-hijri

Tags: javascript, momentjs, hijri

According to the ummul-qura site, 30-Shawwal-1400 is a valid date , but it is returned as invalid when passed throught isValid function using moment-hijri plugin

`moment('1400-10-30', 'iYYYY-iMM-iDD').isValid()`
, What could be the issue?

https://www.ummulqura.org.sa/yearcalender.aspx?y=1400&l=True

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE

Using this code in `moment-hijri.js` right after the closing brackets at line 121, dates seems to work correctly. By the way, you should check it deeply to be sure that everything is ok.

```js
...
79517, 79546, 79576, 79606, 79635, 79665, 79694, 79724, 79753, 79783, 79812, 79841, 79871, 79900, 79930, 79960, 79990]
}

// Add this code 
for (let i = 538; i < ummalqura.ummalquraData.length; i++) {
 ummalqura.ummalquraData[i] += 1;
}
```

(Otherwise, you can also decrease constants from 0 to 537 by 1, it's the same solution.)

If a month has 29 or 30 days depends on a simple calculation: `ummalquraData[i] - ummalquraData[i - 1]`. In your case, `ummalquraData[538] - ummalquraData[537]` returns 29 instead of expected 30. To obtain 30 preserving every other calculation you need to increase every constant after 538 (included) OR decrease every constant before 538 (excluded). This way, you're changing only the duration of 1400-10, keeping original duration of every other month.

#### UPDATE (not valid solution)

I have found a (seems to be) valid solution for you. Using constant data from here (https://github.com/talomaireeni/Umm-Al-Qura-Calendar/blob/master/UQCal.js), i see that `1400-10` is correctly validated.

Be careful, this library starts from `15141` (line 17) while `moment-hijri` starts from `28607` (line 39). Switching `moment-hijri` constants with the ones from this library, everything seems to work.

I suggest you to open an issue in the official `moment-hijri`'s GitHub repository and ask for a fix.

Meanwhile, you can use `UQCal.js`'s constants to fix your app.

#### UPDATE (old)

Analyzing the library's source code, i found that the main problem is generated by this function (which bases its calculations on constants):

```js
// moment-hijri.js at line 806

hMoment.iDaysInMonth = function (year, month) {
    var i = getNewMoonMJDNIndex(year, month + 1),
    daysInMonth = ummalqura.ummalquraData[i] - ummalqura.ummalquraData[i - 1]
    return daysInMonth
}



// moment-hijri.js at line 29

/************************************
      Constants
  ************************************/

    var ummalqura = {
        ummalquraData: [28607, 28636, 28665, 28695, 28724, ...
```

This function returns the number of days in a month providing specific `year` and `month` values. Providing `1400` and `10` it returns `29` days (instead of expected `30`).

`getNewMoonMJDNIndex()` finds the *index of the new moon in modified Julian day number* (`moment-hijri.js` at line 935) in `ummalquraData`, which contains constant data.

So, the problem is caused by wrong constant data inside `ummalquraData` which consider `1400-10` of 29 days.

Here are my tests:

```js
    it('should add one day in the same month', function() {
      var m = moment('1400-10-29', 'iYYYY-iMM-iDD');
      m.add(1, 'idate')
      m.format('iYYYY-iM-iD').should.be.equal('1400-10-30')
    })
    // AssertionError: expected '1400-11-1' to equal '1400-10-30'


    it('should confirm that 1400-09 has 30 days', function() {
      var daysInMonth = moment('1400-09-15', 'iYYYY-iMM-iDD').iDaysInMonth();
      daysInMonth.should.be.equal(30);
    })
    // Pass, 1400-09 has 30 days


    it('FALSE POSITIVE should confirm that 1400-10 has 30 days', function() {
      // After an internal conversion, the date becomes 1400-11-01 (so the month becomes '11')
      // That's why iDaysInMonth() returns 30 (that seems correct).
      var daysInMonth = moment('1400-10-30', 'iYYYY-iMM-iDD').iDaysInMonth();
      daysInMonth.should.be.equal(30);
    })
    // Pass, but it's a false positive


    it('should confirm that 1400-10 has 30 days', function() {
      // After an internal conversion, the date becomes 1400-11-01 (so the month becomes '11')
      // That's why iDaysInMonth() returns 30 (that seems correct).
      var daysInMonth = moment('1400-10-15', 'iYYYY-iMM-iDD').iDaysInMonth();
      daysInMonth.should.be.equal(30);
    })
    // AssertionError: expected 29 to equal 30
```

#### OLD ANSWER

Accordingly to multiple online Hijri calendars, 1400-10-30 is not a valid date:

https://www.mumineencalendar.com/#
If you set 1400 Shawwal and click on '30', you'll see that '30' is referred to Gregorian Calendar - 30 August 1980 - and the "real" last day of Shawwal is 29.

This is a bit strange, every month seems to leak the last day, anyway it confirms that 1400-10-30 is not a valid date: https://www.islamicfinder.org/islamic-calendar/1400/Shawwal/?type=Hijri

So, the `isValid()` method seems to work correctly.

Comment: The calendars you specified are not same as Umm ul qura calendar adopted by Saudi Arabia for adminitstrative purposes, you can see more details here
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar#Saudi_Arabia's_Umm_al-Qura_calendar

moment-hijri is based on Ummul qura - https://github.com/xsoh/moment-hijri

Comment: @Zuhair sorry for the first answer, i didn't know the difference between two calendars. I've done further research and updated my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks so much for a thorough analysis, extremely appreciated, What could be the fix? Shoudl we check some other Umm-ul-qura js packages or libraries and figure out the constant to change in ummalquraData ?

Comment: @Zuhair found a reliable solution, check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, but isn't the constant diyanet_dat in the https://github.com/talomaireeni/Umm-Al-Qura-Calendar/blob/master/UQCal.js  starting from 15141, there is a ummulqura_dat (L151) which looks similar to what we have in moment-hijri ?

Comment: Sorry for my misreading, you're right, the right constant is the one at L151. Anyway, i've checked 3 different libraries (https://github.com/msarhan/ummalqura-calendar/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/msarhan/ummalqura/calendar/UmmalquraGregorianConverter.java, https://gist.github.com/akmalxxx/6492017, http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Development/calendar/com_sahaab_hijricalendarHijriCalendarDate_java.htm) and none of them seems to work as you expected. I've updated my answer with a last chance, you must check it against all your dates to be sure that it works.

Comment: I see that you are adding 1 to constant after 538 index, let me test & get back, Thnx for the help, highly appreciated, Cheers

Comment: You can also decrease constants from 0 to 537 by 1, it's the same solution. If a month has 29 or 30 days depends on a simple calculation: `ummalquraData[i] - ummalquraData[i - 1]`. In your case, `ummalquraData[538] - ummalquraData[537]` returns 29 instead of expected 30. To obtain 30 without altering every other calculation, we need to increase every constant after 538 (included) OR decrease every constant before 538 (excluded). Updated answer to clarify a bit

Comment: @Zuhair does my last solution work?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, the problem is length of the month is different for the whole the year 1400 according to the ummul qura site vs the library, confused now what should be the way forward

Comment: I am using https://github.com/umalqura/umalqura/tree/master library as if fixes my issues